# Katalon Studio - reference separate Git repo from one project

Tags: katalon-studio

Is it possible to reference a 2nd Git repository to utilize files from it if I'm using a different project within Katalon studio, which was created from a separate Git repo?

I have 2 Git repos, one with my web UI test cases and another with the Object Repositories (I kept them separate so test cases from different projects could all reference the same object repo). Is it possible within Katalon Studio, when I have my test cases project open, to somehow reference the object repo from the separate Git repo? I'm just trying to avoid having to duplicate the objects within each project which may use an object on a particular page.

Answer (score 1):

It will be a complicated setup
 1 - Items in Test cases and Object repository are not saved in a single folder, but many folder instead. The relationship between them has an ID, so saving them separately easily break the reference.
 2 - In git, you have to specify as main git and sub module. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/GitSubmodules/article.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll follow up on that link and see what happens.